# Lighttable cannot connect - error running Clojure REPL

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I get the error mentioned here:

https://github.com/LightTable/LightTable/issues/1052

I tried `lein deps :tree` as suggested there and I got this:

```
as-MacBook-Air:~ a$ lein deps :tree
Couldn't find project.clj, which is needed for deps
as-MacBook-Air:~ a$
```

I don't know how to fix this. Can you help?

This is not specific to lighttable. Same thing happens with Atom and emacs.

Answer (score 0):

You're running leingen outside of your project directory (according to the output, you're just running it into your home directory). You need to run it in the directory where you checked out LightTable - it has a project.clj file